# How to tokenise text to use as input for a keras neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I'm trying to perform sentiment analysis over a dataset composed of labeled english text labeled with a number between (0,4).

I've been following the tensorflow guide on this from here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_text_classification
adapted to suit my multiclass classification problem.

A sample of the dataset is here:

```
PhraseId,SentenceId,Phrase,Sentiment
21071,942,irony,1
63332,3205,Blue Crush ' swims away with the Sleeper Movie of the Summer award .,2
142018,7705,in the third row of the IMAX cinema,2
103601,5464,images of a violent battlefield action picture,2 .
12235,523,an engrossing story,3
77679,3994,should come with the warning `` For serious film buffs only !,2
58875,2969,enjoyed it,3
152071,8297,"A delicious , quirky movie with a terrific screenplay and fanciful direction by Michael Gondry .",4
```

Currently, my model performs very badly, with a constant accuracy of about 0.5, and this doesn't change across epochs.

I know how to tune the model's hyperparameters and all of the tricks I can try there, but nothing seems to help. I'm convinced that I've made a mistake somewhere in processing the data, since this is my first time doing deep learning with textual data.

My current preprocessing consists of:

- Removing the PhraseID and SentenceID columns from the dataset
- Removing punctuation and upper case letters
- Shuffling the order of the dataset
- Separating the data and labels into different dataframes
- One-hot encoding the labels
- Tokenizing the data using the Keras preprocessing Tokenizer
- Padding the sequences to the same length

I think there's an issue in the tokenization stage, or maybe I just don't understand how the model takes the tokenized words as an input vector and can learn from it.

My relevant tokenization code is:

```
    def tokenize_data(self, df, max_features=5000):
    self.logger.log(f'Tokenizing with {max_features} features')
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, split=' ')
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df.values)
    train_set = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df.values)
    if self.logger.verbose_f : self.logger.verbose(train_set[:10])
    return train_set

def pad_sequences(self, data, maxlen=5000):
    result = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(data,
                                                    value=0,
                                                    padding='post',
                                                    maxlen=maxlen)
    if self.logger.verbose_f:
        df = pd.DataFrame(result)
        df.to_csv("processed.csv")

    return result
```

The output of the pad sequences looks like this:

```
7,821,3794,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

8,74,44,344,325,2904,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

etc etc for each instance.

These values get fed into the model like this to act as the training data.

Do I need to do some sort of normalisation before I give train on this?

Or am I completely barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Most of your data pre processing is fine and it requires no changes.
- Normalizing the data should be performed as the numbers like 0 and 2045 have a great difference between them and will cause the gradients to explode.